# How to get numeric time of day from XTS index, with correct timezone?

Tags: c++, datetime, rcpp

I need a fast numeric representation of the time of day.
Lets start with some basic data:

```
> z1 = structure(
+   c(1:5),.Dim = c(5L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Hour")),
+   index = as.POSIXct(paste("2018-06-06",paste(1:5,":00:00",sep = ""),sep = " "), tz = 'America/Chicago'),
+   .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = 'America/Chicago',
+   tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = 'America/Chicago', class = c("xts", "zoo"))
> z1
                    Hour
2018-06-06 01:00:00    1
2018-06-06 02:00:00    2
2018-06-06 03:00:00    3
2018-06-06 04:00:00    4
2018-06-06 05:00:00    5
> index(z1[1])
[1] "2018-06-06 01:00:00 CDT"
```

So I have 5 times by the hour Chicago time or CDT.
I need to be able to look at the time, like 1AM and get a numeric time like 1/24 = .0416666667.
The XTS index is in Datetime format or seconds from 1970-01-01 so the math should be simple by using the modulo function %%.
Lets try:

```
> cbind(z1,(unclass(index(z1)) %% (60*60*24))/(60*60*24),(unclass(index(z1)) %% (60*60*24))/(60*60*24)*24)
                    Hour       ..2 ..3
2018-06-06 01:00:00    1 0.2500000   6
2018-06-06 02:00:00    2 0.2916667   7
2018-06-06 03:00:00    3 0.3333333   8
2018-06-06 04:00:00    4 0.3750000   9
2018-06-06 05:00:00    5 0.4166667  10
```

I unclass the index (to have the same value rcpp will see) then do the modulo for the seconds in the day to the get the days left over and then hours left over.
The problem is obviously the timezone. The resulting time of day is in UTC time zone, but I need it Chicago time just like the the XTS object. If I could simply get the numeric offset for the timezone it would be easy, but it seems getting the offset is not so simple.

So, I need a function in rcpp that if given an XTS time would give me the time of day in the correct timezone. It can be in days, hours or anything else, as long as it is numeric and fast.

The intended use of this TimeOfDay function is, say for running code during typical workday hours of 9 AM to 5 PM.

```
if(TimeOfDay(Index(1)) > 9.0 && TimeOfDay(Index(1)) < 17.0)
{
   //Code to run.
}
```

Comment: Are you sure need Rcpp for this? This is just time 'math' from `as.POSIXct` and alike.

Comment: I need it for Rcpp specifically as I am running it on ridiculously large data sets and need a fast way to get time of day without being dependent on R. Thank you.

Comment: Trust me, you don't need Rcpp, and I have written a fair amount of R and Rcpp and C++ code.  But your question is not clear because despite writing for several paragraphs I am still not entirely sure what you want here.

Comment: I just need the time of day, so for "2018-06-06 01:00:00 CDT" or 1518678000, the result should be either: 1 for hours, or .046666667 days, or 60 minutes or 3600 seconds and I need it to run in Rcpp.

Comment: See my answer below; I leave adding a `myhour/24`, `myhour*60` and `myhour*60*60` extension to the reader.  And if you "must" have it in Rcpp, I fear you may have to write it.  But you can convert easily to `time` and `struct tm` -- standard time calcs at the C level.  The Rcpp source will give you hints too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple solution using the convenience function in `data.table`:

```
R> z2 <- data.table(pt=index(z1))
R> z2[, myhour:=hour(pt)][]
                    pt myhour
1: 2018-06-06 01:00:00      1
2: 2018-06-06 02:00:00      2
3: 2018-06-06 03:00:00      3
4: 2018-06-06 04:00:00      4
5: 2018-06-06 05:00:00      5
R>
```

We just pass the `POSIXct` object in, and derive hour from it. You'd be hard-pressed to beat it in home-grown C/C++ code -- and this solution already exists.

Comment: Thank you, but doesn't hour only return the hour value, not the full time of day. That means that POSIXct has done the math and parsed out the individual values hour, minute, seconds and then I need to put them back together. Simpler question, is there any way with POSIXct to get just the offset value for the timezone? Thank you.